# Taking from file as input from intellij similar to using terminal <

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal

I am writing a program which calculates the features of a Triangle that takes points(3 coordinates) as input a total of 6 digits each 2 representing 3 coordinates.

I have two files of code Main.java and Triangle.java representing the class i'm implementing.

I didn't want to keep inputting them manually so i made a file input.txt 
where i stored the inputs separated by line by line ontop

```
5
4 
6
4
3 
2
```

I executed

```
javac Main.java  Triangle.java
java Main < input.txt
```

which works, but now I want to do it in intellij CE
cause I like having the debugger which i don't have with just plain files
but in intellij you don't do javac or java you just click "run" and the program is compiled and executed and you can't tell it to read from file for input. I do want to use a file reader in my code since the program will be checked using the "<" so I want to work on it with the equivalent in intellij CE.I tried digging into the src folder and executing the commands from terminal there but i got "could not find or load main class java" after "javac Main" worked. How would I would i do this?